# Backdate in Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to to access the date of a post, link or photo that has been backdated on a Page timeline?

The Graph API provides the created time and updated time, but does not reveal where it falls on the timeline.

For instance, I could post a link on 11/16/12 and set it to 10/31/12 on the timeline, and all I can access via the Graph API is the 11/16/12 date.

Is there a similar field to "start_time", provided with milestones? In this case, the created time can differ from the start time.

Thanks, everyone.

Comment: No, there seems to be no field holding that date in either the API or FQL as of yet. Maybe worth opening a bug report/feature request with Facebook.

Comment: is it still same ? If it is how indiana jones page did it ? http://www.facebook.com/indianajones?ref=br_tf